# counts the characters when reached at some point

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code which is working fine;

```
var text_max = 459;
    var text_used = 0;
    var sms_count = 0;
    $('#leftstring').html(text_max + '');
    $('#usedstring').html(text_used + '');
    $('#sms_count').html(sms_count + '');
    $(document).on("keyup","#Message", function() {
        var text_length = $('#Message').val().length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
        var text_completed = text_used + text_length;
        if(text_length <= 152) {
            var smscounts =+ parseInt(smscounts)+1;
        }
        $('#leftstring').html(text_remaining + '');
        $('#usedstring').html(text_completed + '');
        $('#sms_count').html(smscounts + '');
    });
```

Issue is with the `sms_count` as what i am trying is: i have a limit of `459` characters, so i want to divide it by `3`, so when the characters reach `152`, it should count to `1` and then for next `152` it should count `2` and then for last `152` it should count to `3`

Comment: Ok. A lot of: I have, I want and it should, but you forgot to mention the actual problem you are having

Comment: If you're intending this to be similar to real life, you're going to need to understand Unicode and its various encodings. One Unicode codepoint could take 3 or more bytes in an SMS message.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use `Math.ceil()` to find the minimum number of messages that would have to be sent.

```
var per_text = 152

$(document).on("keyup","#Message", function() {
    var text_length = $('#Message').val().length;
    var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
    var text_completed = text_used + text_length;
    var smscounts = Math.ceil(text_length / per_text);

    $('#leftstring').html(text_remaining + '');
    $('#usedstring').html(text_completed + '');
    $('#sms_count').html(smscounts + '');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should logistically accomplish what you stated:

```
    ...
    if(text_length <= 152) {
        var smscounts =+ parseInt(smscounts)+1;
    } else if (text_length <= 304) {
      //do logic
    } else { // it's > 304
      //do logic
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
var sms=152,text_max=3*sms; // good idea from caliburn, thanx ;-)
$(document).on("keyup","#Message", function() {
  var text_length = $('#Message').val().length;
  $('#leftstring').html((text_max - text_length) + '');
  $('#usedstring').html((text_length % sms) + '');
  $('#sms_count').html(Math.ceil(text_length / sms) + '');
});
```

see here: http://jsfiddle.net/fkgpwhb5/

Answer (score 0):

You want this

```
smscounts = Math.ceil(text_length / 152);
```

Math.ceil will round up to the nearest integer. Since JavaScript division is a little wonky, you might have to do this instead

```
smscounts = Math.floor(text_length / 152) + 1;
```